# Why does Spark writes dataframe to different file sizes and different time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider general algorithm:

```
val first : DataFrame = ...            // about 100 Mb
val second : DataFrame = ...           // about 5 GMb 
val third : DataFrame = ...            // about 7 GMb
val fourth : DataFrame = ...           // about 13 GMb

//all dataframe are filtered, renamed all columns. A new colun is added into `third` and `fourth`  

val = firstAndSecond = first.join(first("first_id") === second("second_id"))
val = thirdsAndAll = firstAndSecond.join(firstAndSecond("some_id") === third("third_id"))
val = fourthAndAll = thirdsAndAll.join(thirdsAndAll("other_id") === fourth("fourth_id"))

fourthAndAll.write.mode(saveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("file://C:path")
```

**Notes***

1. All data frames are read to and written from SSD drive.
2. Read and write operation performed to/in parquet files
3. Program was run on to Threadripper with 8 cores (16 virtual), 80Gb Ram (spark consumed about 25Gb), also 99% of time
   (except the situation when last file is writeen) all 16 cores are loaded 100%.

**The problem**

I have very different sizes in output parquet files from 100 kb to 500Nb. Also bigger files have very long time to write.
E.g. Every file is writen by some threads which wrote 500Mb, 450Mb (etc.) files perform their work too long. (for 500Mb it was about 8 hours)

Any thoughts how to setup spark to write parquet file with more or less equal size CPU load?

Comment: always a good idea to do `df.repartition(x).write. ...` which will write x number of part files with roughly equal sizes. That'll mean each task for write completes in roughly the same time. Increasing `x` will cause more files to be written. That's more parallelism with smaller size for each task so the job will complete much faster. However you don't want too many files or too small files if you're gonna read them as a dataframe again.

Answer (score 0):

(I work mostly with `RDD`s, have not much experience with dataframe api but I guess it works the same way)

I guess `.parquet` creates a file per partition of the rdd. If file sizes are drastically different then the data is not evenly distributed across partitions.
It also could decrease the performance of `join` operation. `repartition` command should help.